# Using bibtex, how do I cite a musical composition?

Tags: bibtex, music

For example

> S. Reich.  It’s Gonna Rain. 1965.

Comment: This might not be on-topic; perhaps better-suited on [academia.se]?

Comment: What about using `@misc`. It takes `author`, `title` and `year` as fields.

Comment: This depends on your citation style guide. If you use the Chicago Manual of Style, 16th edition, you can cite published musical compositions the same as a book. (But then you should use `biblatex-chicago`). The composer is the author, and the other fields would be the same. For an unpublished composition, treat it like a dissertation or other unpublished manuscript.

Comment: biblatex has (unsupported) entry types for musical recordings: `@audio` and `@music`, wiche are formatted by default as `@misc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you gave not more information one can only guess which document class, or bibliography style you use, if you call `biblatex` or not etc.

The following bib entry works for standard `bibtex`:

```
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
```

It gives the data of Mozarts Sinfonie g-Moll. It was endet in year 1773, has the number 183 in the new Köchelverzeichnis, number 25 in the old version.

Depending on your used style and/or program `bibtex` or `biber` you have to rework it.

With standard `bibtex` you get as result:

[image]